# Write permissions denied on linked tables between MS Access 2003 and 2007

Tags: microsoft-access

We are in the process of switching over to Access 2007.  We have numerous data tables in Access 2003 files.

In one case, the user has 2007 on his PC and opened the front end in 2007.  No problems.

When the the user is done, he clicks a button that executes a macro full of update queries.  The macro reaches the first query and halts.  We get a message saying we do not have permissions to write to this linked table (2003 format).  There were no security files involved.  We re-linked from 2007, same problem.  LAN permssions were ok.

I wound up having to import the tables to front end in order for the user to be able to do his job.

Comment: Does the 2007 machine have a different OS than the 2003 machines? If it's Vista (instead of XP) there may be file permissions / user rights that need to be granted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this particular instance had linked tables and a macro with about 30 steps which 2007 would not execute.

Put the tables back in with the rest of the application and it works fine in either 2003 or 2007.